# Firestore Transaction fails if document existed in the past

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction(
  (transaction) {
    return transaction.get(reportDocRef).then((reportDoc) {
      if (reportDoc.exists) {
        if (reportDoc.data()!['processed'] != true) {
          transaction.update(reportDocRef, reportMap);
        }
      } else {
        transaction.set(reportDocRef, reportMap);
      }
    });
  },
);
```

This is a simple Firestore transaction running with Flutter:

1. First run -> creates a new document since none exists at the referenced path
2. Second run -> document exists so it checks if field 'processed' is not set and if so writes an update, otherwise doesn't write/update anything.

Everything runs fine until I delete the document, either manually through the console or using the admin SDK. At this point I would assume this takes us back to step 1 but instead the transaction fails with the following error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception:
> [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because
> the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution.
> If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase
> console.

Somehow deleting a document is not equivalent to not having that document to begin with. **Why does this code work before the document is created but not after it is deleted?**

I tried this same code in the admin SDK and there is no problem, so this only happen on mobile.

*This is running on the firebase emulators and flutter on an android emulator, all running on Windows 11.*

Comment: Given the error, I'm surprised if this only happens with the client-side SDK. Are you testing on iOS, Android, or web? And: can you reproduce against a regular (non emulator) project?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It does indeed only happen on client SDK according to my tests. I'm testing on an Android emulator. I switched to an actual firebase project instead of the emulator suite and tried the same code again, this time it works fine without raising any errors, so it creates the document again after deletion as I expected. One oddity is that after deletion I cant see the document created again unless I refresh the console (F5).

Comment: In that case it sounds like you might have discovered a bug in the Firestore emulator, and I recommend filing a bug on [its repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sure, I will. Is it correct behavior to use transaction.get to check if a document.exists without a catch block or is it supposed to raise an exception if the document is not found?